# Buttons on toolbar do not work when app launch from background?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uitoolbar

I am facing a weird problem in my app.

I have few buttons on toolbar when tapped presents a popovercontroller. If the app is taken to background (by pressing home button) while popover is visible, on relaunch from background buttons on the toolbar doesn't work. However if i touch somewhere in the popover or out side toolbar boundaries popover is dismissed and app work fine.

Any idea or suggestion??

Comment: Then best way is remove/hide/dismiss your popovercontroller when you are enter in background mode..

Comment: @iPatel :is there any other way like i don't want to dismiss the popover for some reasons??

Comment: So please put your relevant code .. :)